Open-source alternatives to System.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer for Hebrew TTS in C#
I'm developing a C# application that requires Text-to-Speech (TTS) functionality in Hebrew.
I initially attempted to use the built-in System.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer library.
However, as expected, it doesn't provide native support for Hebrew voices,
resulting in the GetInstalledVoices method not finding any Hebrew options.
Additionally, the Speak method wouldn't produce any output due to the lack of a suitable voice.
this my test
class Program
{
  static async Task Main()
  {
    // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    var x = synth.GetInstalledVoices(); // This won't find Hebrew voices
    // Configure the audio output.
    synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    // Speak a string (won't produce output due to missing Hebrew voice).
    synth.Speak("בדיקה");
  }
}




as expected not at all. System.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer is the API to the Windows Speech API. It uses whatever packages are installed on your machine. Can you use Hebrew with the built-in Windows applications to begin with?

When did you install the Hebrew package? When I install it I get a warning that the settings page and all applications that use speech have to close first. That includes applications like the browser. Almost all applications can use accessibility features like speech. I do see a Greek voice, as I installed the Greek package years ago, so the machine has already gone through restarts

The settings page has a link to the list of voices by package. Just as I have Microsoft Stefanos installed you should see Microsoft Asaf after a succesful installation

@Panagiotis Kanavos restarting the computer didn't affect this issue

After following the instructions listed in @morcibacsi's answer
problem solved

